# How would I translate this C# code into PHP?

Tags: c#, php, porting

I need a PHP version of the following C# code:

```
string dateSince = "2010-02-01";
string siteID = "bash.org";
string sharedSecret = "12345"; // the same combination on my luggage!

using System.Security.Cryptography;

MD5CryptoServiceProvider x = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] dataBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}",   dateSince,  siteID, sharedSecret));
string result = BitConverter.ToString(x.ComputeHash(dataBytes));
```

... this code snippet appears to be incomplete.  But here's what I think is going on:

1. concatenating dateSince, siteID, and sharedSecret.  Stealing underpants.
2. ???
3. converting that string into a ascii encoded byte array.
4. taking the MD5 hash of that array.

This mysterious BitConverter object appears to be converting that MD5 hashed array, into a string of hexadecimal numbers.  According to the aforementioned doc, the value of result should look something like: "6D-E9-9A-B6-73-D8-10-79-BC-4F-EE-51-A4-84-15-D8"

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

---

Forgot to include this earlier.  Here's the PHP version of what I've written so far:

```
$date_since = "2010-02-01";
$site_id = "bash.org";
$shared_secret = "12345";

$initial_token = $date_since.$site_id.$shared_secret;

$ascii_version = array();
foreach($i=0; $i < strlen($initial_token); $i++) {
    $ascii_version[] = ord(substr($initial_token,$i,1));
}

$md5_version = md5(join("", $ascii_version));

$hexadecimal_bits = array();
foreach($i=0; $i < strlen($md5_version); $i++) {
   // @todo convert to hexadecimal here?
   $hexadecimal_bits[] = bin2hex(substr($md5_version,$i,1));
}

$result = join("-", $hexadecimal_bits);
```

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally don't like to just write your code for you.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that; I am new here.  One moment....

Comment: +1 for same combination as your luggage.

Comment: But that is why it is a "shared secret" ;-)

Comment: That's the same combination on my planet's air lock!

Comment: I can see this whole thing gearing toward a lecture about best security practices. Haha.

Comment: did you mean hexadecimal_bytes? :)  Also, what's wrong with your code?  It looks like you already solved your own problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work for you.  It looks like the MD5CryptoServiceProvider::ComputeHash method returns an array of 16 bytes, not a string of 32 characters like the normal PHP `md5()` function.  However, PHP's `md5()` has a second optional parameter that forces "raw output", which *does* correspond to the output of `ComputeHash()`.

```
$date_since = "2010-02-01";
$site_id = "bash.org";
$shared_secret = "12345";
$initial_token = $date_since.$site_id.$shared_secret;

//get the RAW FORMAT md5 hash
//corresponds to the output of MD5CryptoServiceProvider::ComputeHash
$str = md5($initial_token, true);
$len = strlen($str);
$hex = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    //convert the byte to a hex string representation (left padded with zeros)
    $hex[] = str_pad(dechex(ord($str[$i])), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
//dump output
echo implode("-",$hex);

//outputs fe-0d-58-fd-5f-3d-83-fe-0f-6a-02-b4-94-0c-aa-7b
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!  It makes a lot more sense now.  You're a great help zombat.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I see except that what it outputs won't input the dashes. Those would have to be injected some other way.

```
var $dateSince = "2010-02-01"; 
var $siteID = "bash.org"; 
var $sharedSecret = "12345"; // the same combination on my luggage! 

var $full_string = $dateSince . $siteID . $sharedSecret;

string result = md5($full_string);
```